# SQL view all courses in which student is enrolled

Tags: mysql

I have a problem building a query in which I will select course's descriptions for students who enrolled in this course. My tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
 (STUDENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
 ,SALUTATION VARCHAR(5)
 ,FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(25)
 ,LAST_NAME VARCHAR(25) 
 ,STREET_ADDRESS VARCHAR(50)
 ,ZIP VARCHAR(5) 
 ,PHONE VARCHAR(15)
 ,EMPLOYER VARCHAR(50)
 ,REGISTRATION_DATE DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`STUDENT_ID`)
 );

CREATE TABLE COURSE(
 COURSE_NO INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT 
 ,DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50) 
 ,COST FLOAT
 ,CREATED_DATE DATETIME
 ,PRIMARY KEY (`COURSE_NO`)
 );

CREATE TABLE SECTION
 (SECTION_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  
 ,COURSE_NO INTEGER   
 ,START_DATE_TIME DATE
 ,LOCATION VARCHAR(50)
 ,INSTRUCTOR_ID INTEGER
 ,PRIMARY KEY (`SECTION_ID`)
 ,FOREIGN KEY(INSTRUCTOR_ID) REFERENCES INSTRUCTOR(INSTRUCTOR_ID)
 ,FOREIGN KEY(COURSE_NO) REFERENCES COURSE(COURSE_NO)
 );

CREATE TABLE ENROLLMENT(
  STUDENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
 ,SECTION_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
 ,ENROLL_DATE DATE 
 ,FINAL_GRADE FLOAT
 ,FOREIGN KEY(STUDENT_ID) REFERENCES STUDENT(STUDENT_ID)
 ,FOREIGN KEY(SECTION_ID) REFERENCES SECTION(SECTION_ID)
 );
```

I tried something with JOINS but it seems too complicated to me:

```
SELECT s.FIRST_NAME, s.LAST_NAME, c.SECTION_ID 
FROM SECTION c 
INNER JOIN ENROLLMENT sc ON c.ID = sc.SECTION_ID
INNER JOIN STUDENT s ON sc.STUDENT_ID = s.STUDENT_ID
WHERE sc.STUDENT_ID = 1;
```

Comment: Do u expect result based on course description? but search condition of your query with student_id. Please explain

Comment: @RahulBiswas I want to select all courses for a given student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve student's enrolled course info. If search for specific student then enable e.student_id = 1 or if search for all students then disable e.student_id = 1 or if search for few students i.e 1, 2, 5 then use e.student_id IN (1, 2, 5)

```
-- MySQL
SELECT st.first_name, st.last_name
     , c.course_no, c.description
     , c.cost, e.enroll_date
FROM SECTION s
INNER JOIN ENROLLMENT e
        ON s.section_id = e.section_id
       AND e.student_id = 1
INNER JOIN COURSE c
        ON c.course_no = s.course_no
INNER JOIN STUDENT st
        ON st.student_id = e.student_id
```

Comment: @BrianBrown please check this answer.

Comment: Welcome @BrianBrown and also thanks for upvote. If this answer help you then please mark it as accepted along with upvote so that anyone can pick this answer without any doubt.